# Differentiation of complex valued functions. $i^x$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

The question is how to find the derivative of $i^x$ or even if it exists?. WolframAlpha does give an answer. 
Before applying the definition, we see that how can we mix the complex and the real plane. So IMHO, I don't think that we can apply the definition for finding this functions derivative. Even if we do,:- 
$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{i^{x+h}-i^x}{h}=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{i^{x}(i^h-1)}{h}$$ 
Now what to do?

Comment: How do you define properly $i^x$?

Comment: In complex analysis, we define $i^x = e^{x \ln{i}}$. The derivative of this can be easily computed.

Comment: @Nitin : I suppose you take the principal value of the logarithm... but that's kinda arbitrary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use $i=e^{i\pi/2}$ to get $i^x=e^{i\pi x/2}$ and differentiate to get $\dfrac{i\pi}{2}e^{i\pi x/2}=\dfrac{i\pi}{2}i^x$

Comment: Why $i=e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$ and not $i=e^{5i\frac{\pi}{2}}$? This is another possible choice but would gives you another derivative !

Comment: complex numbers are multi-valued, see a definition of ln(i)

Comment: Then the derivative of $i^x$ is multivalued too

Comment: Understood! (y)

Answer (score 2):

$i^x$ for natural or integer $n = x$ performs rotations $90n$ degrees. The natural expansion for real $x$ would be the function which rotates along the unit circle and then the derivative should become the "velocity vector" encoded as a complex number. If we look at Jon's answer above, that's exactly what happens. We got a constant factor $i\pi/2$ which always points in the tangent direction to the circle.

Tried adding a webm video, but this will have to do. Rotates anti-clockwise, the derivative being along the unit circle tangent the whole time.
[image]